# Combine two dimensional vs one dimensional array in numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have two numpy arrays like this,

```
data1 = np.array([[17, 48],
                  [17, 53],
                  [17, 55]])
data2 = np.array([100,200])
```

I want to combine those arrays by adding 1 at the beginning of the each one.

I tried,

```
out = []
for i in data1:
    for j in data2:
        out.append([1,i,j])
np.array(out)

#array([[1, array([17, 48]), 100],
#       [1, array([17, 48]), 200],
#       [1, array([17, 53]), 100],
#       [1, array([17, 53]), 200],
#       [1, array([17, 55]), 100],
#       [1, array([17, 55]), 200]], dtype=object)
```

But the output is not the one I desire. The expected one is like below.

```
data_desired = np.array([[1,17,48,100],
                         [1,17,48,200],
                         [1,17,53,100],
                         [1,17,53,200],
                         [1,17,55,100],
                         [1,17,55,200]])
```

By the way, using loop seems also wrong to me. Maybe there exist some other alternatives like broadcasting, newaxis etc?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the unpacking operator `*` to unpack `i`. This is probably the easiest fix for your situation.

```
out = []
for i in data1:
    for j in data2:
        out.append([1,*i,j])
np.array(out)
```

Comment: Thanks @Blupper . I did not know about the unpacking operator. Upvoted!

Comment: You're welcome @datatech . Thanks for the upvote. Check out [this](https://stackabuse.com/unpacking-in-python-beyond-parallel-assignment/) blog post for more use cases of the `*` operator.

Answer (score 2):

If speed is relevant and you are going to use large arrays, you shouldn't use loops or growing data structures:

```
>>> n1 = len(data1)
>>> n2 = len(data2)
>>> result = np.empty_like(data1, shape=(n1*n2, 4))
>>> result[:, 0] = 1
>>> result[:, 1:3] = np.repeat(data1, n2, axis=0)
>>> result[:, 3] = np.repeat(data2[None, :], m1, axis=0).ravel()
>>> result
array([[  1,  17,  48, 100],
       [  1,  17,  48, 200],
       [  1,  17,  53, 100],
       [  1,  17,  53, 200],
       [  1,  17,  55, 100],
       [  1,  17,  55, 200]])
```

Comment: I worked out a variant using broadcasting instead of `repeat`.

Answer (score 1):

A variant on @aerobiomat's answer, using broadcasting instead of `repeat` to fill in the data.  `reshape` produces a view, so assignment to it affects `res` itself.  Working this out took some experimenting, so it's not necessarily superior.

```
In [141]: res = np.ones((6,4),data1.dtype)
In [142]: res.reshape((3,2,4))[:,:,1:3]=data1[:,None,:]
In [143]: res.reshape((3,2,4))[:,:,3]=data2
In [144]: res
Out[144]: 
array([[  1,  17,  48, 100],
       [  1,  17,  48, 200],
       [  1,  17,  53, 100],
       [  1,  17,  53, 200],
       [  1,  17,  55, 100],
       [  1,  17,  55, 200]])
```

The reshaped array looks like:

```
In [145]: res.reshape((3,2,4))
Out[145]: 
array([[[  1,  17,  48, 100],
        [  1,  17,  48, 200]],

       [[  1,  17,  53, 100],
        [  1,  17,  53, 200]],

       [[  1,  17,  55, 100],
        [  1,  17,  55, 200]]])
```